# Solr: setting useCompoundFile to be true doesn't have any effect on the index files

Tags: solr

In SolrConfig.xml, i set below:

```
<useCompoundFile>true</useCompoundFile>
```

But once i reindex my stuff, i still see a bunch of index files ranged from _0* to _9*, instead of seeing a single index file.

Question:

```
1. how to fix this?
2. if i update index at the run time, is it ok to use compound index then?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

those are segments files, see [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/fileformats.html#File%20Naming). Those don't mean compound files are not being used, check [with this doc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/fileformats.html#Compound%20Files) to make sure. Basically look for .cfx files in the index dir.

Comment: Thanks Persimmonium. The thing is i have multiple *.fdt, *.fdx, *.fnm, *.frq, *.nrm, *.prx, *.tii and *.tis files, 8 groups of them; and i got only one *.cfs file. I wonder if these can be reduced to only one group.